# Show that $\partial_j f$ exists at any point and is equal to $\partial^{dist}_{j} f$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative, distribution-theory

> Show that f $f\in C(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\partial^{dist}_{j} f\in C(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then $\partial_j f$ exists at any point and is equal to $\partial^{dist}_{j} f$.

Where $\partial^{dist}_{j}$ is the derivaet in the distributional sense and $\partial_{j}$ is the derivate in the classic sense.

My approach: iIf $h$ is a mollifier, then $f*h_{\epsilon}$ is $C^{\infty}$. then $$\partial_{j}(f*h_{\epsilon})=\partial^{dist}_{j}(f*h_{\epsilon})=(\partial^{dist}_{j} f)*h_{\epsilon}$$

Now if take $\epsilon\to 0$

$$\partial_{j}(f*h_{\epsilon})=(\partial^{dist}_{j} f)*h_{\epsilon}\to \partial^{dist}_{j} f$$

But how can prove that this implies $\partial_{j} f$ exists at any point and is equal to $\partial^{dist}_{j} f$

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned convergence holds uniformly on compact sets (at least if the support of the mollifier is compact). Thus, we can interchange integration and the limes $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$ to find
\begin{align*}
\int_a^b (\partial_j^{\mathrm{dist}} f )(x) \, dx_j &= \lim_{ \varepsilon \downarrow 0} \int_a^b \partial_j(f \ast h_\varepsilon)(x) \, d x_j \\
& =\lim_{ \varepsilon \downarrow 0} f \ast h_\varepsilon (x_1,\ldots,x_{j-1},b,x_{j+1},\ldots, x_n) - f \ast h_\varepsilon (x_1,\ldots,x_{j-1},a,x_{j+1},\ldots, x_n) \\
&= f (x_1,\ldots,x_{j-1},b,x_{j+1},\ldots, x_n) - f (x_1,\ldots,x_{j-1},a,x_{j+1},\ldots, x_n).
\end{align*}
Now the one-dimensional fundamental theorem of calculus states that the derivate in the $j$-th direction exists and is exactly $(\partial_j^{\mathrm{dist}} f )(x)$. Since the partial derivates are continuous, we conclude that $f$ is continuously differentiable.